# How to get Parent Data with child has apply condition on child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I don't know what will be my question title.

I have two class

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection<Spec> Specs { get; set; }
}

public class Spec
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to get Product with  Specification if Specification IsActive is true  IN LINQ.
I have try but not get any Result.

```
var products = db.Products.Where(x => x.Specs.All(a => a.IsActive)).ToList();
```

But My Expected result is not getting.

Comment: I think you might want [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) not [`All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new List<Product>();

        p.Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Specs = new List<Spec>() { new Spec() { Id = 90, IsActive = true }, new Spec() { Id = 91, IsActive = false } } });
        p.Add(new Product() { Id = 2, Specs = new List<Spec>() { new Spec() { Id = 92, IsActive = false }, new Spec() { Id = 93, IsActive = false } } });
        p.Add(new Product() { Id = 3, Specs = new List<Spec>() { new Spec() { Id = 94, IsActive = true}, new Spec() { Id = 95, IsActive = true} } });
        p.Add(new Product() { Id = 4, Specs = new List<Spec>() { new Spec() { Id = 96, IsActive = true }, new Spec() { Id = 97, IsActive = true } } });


        //Brings Products with ALL Spec.IsActive True
        var products = p.Where(x => x.Specs.All(a => a.IsActive)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("ALL ->" + string.Join(",", products.Select(pro => pro.Id.ToString()).ToArray()));
        //result is 3,4

        //Brings Products with ANY Spec.IsActive True
        var products2 = p.Where(x => x.Specs.Any(a => a.IsActive)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("ANY ->" + string.Join(",", products2.Select(pro => pro.Id.ToString()).ToArray()));
        //result is 1,3,4

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Spec> Specs { get; set; }
}

public class Spec
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }


    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost correct that I need.
but there is a little  bit problem 

In Product Id = 1 
there is two Spec one is true other is false.
I need only true.

Comment: Edited the answer according to your needs, check the difference between using ALL and ANY. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You get products from database. Lazy Loading products will not load the Specs, try to include them:

```
var products = db.Products.Include("Specs").Where(x=>x.Specs.All(a=>a.IsActive)).ToList();
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP does not get any items in the `products` collection. By using `Include()` you're just telling EF to populate the navigation properties with data. But if you don't get any Product entries in the first place that doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh i thought he wants to get if all specs are active, and yet not achieving what he wants